# Promises with Fetch and Throwing Errors

Tags: javascript

I am having a problem when I throw an error in the first .then block, the .catch block does not catch the error that has been thrown. It just displays the error in the .catch block.

Here is a link to the code:
[Code Pen Example](https://codepen.io/muzikman/pen/KKXoMLz)

```
    const getCountryData = country => {
  // Country 1
  fetch(`https://restcountries.com/v2/name/${country}`)
    .then(response => {
      if (!response.ok)
        throw new Error(`Country not found (${response.status})`);

      return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
      renderCountry(data[0]);
      const neighbor = data[0].borders[0];
      if (!neighbor) return;

      // Country 2
      return fetch(`https://restcountries.com/v2/alpha/${neighbor}`);
    })
    .then(response => {
      if (!response.ok)
        throw new Error(`Country not found (${response.status})`);
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
      renderCountry(data, 'neighbour');
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(`${err}  `),
        renderError(`Something went wrong ${err.message}. Try again!`);
    })
    .finally(fade => {
      countriesContainer.style.opacity = 1;
    });
};

btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
  getCountryData('portu=gal');
});
```

Comment: First correct `getCountryData('portu=gal');` to `getCountryData('portugal');`

Comment: I want it to throw an error. That's why I spelled the country incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the country is not found response.ok is true but the data[0] is undefined. That is because response.json gives `{status:404,message:”not found”}`. So your check for whether the country is found should change to

```js
If (data.status === 404) throw new Error(“not found”)
```

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. The .catch block is still overriding the message. Even though I throw an error in the .then block, the .catch block executes but doesn't use my errors. When I use  ```fetch(`https://restcountries.com/v2/name/${country}`)
    .then(response => {
          if (response.status === 404) throw new Error('Country not found');
      return response.json();
    })```I would rather check for the ```response.ok``` as it returns a Boolean. It doesn't matter what I display for now.

Comment: I'm following an instructor led course. It works the way I want it to when I do it your way but I have to throw the error in the second .then. When I throw it in the first .then, it doesn't work. Why not?

Comment: I think I get it. In the first .then block, even when the wrong country is put in, the fetch object status is 200. So, if I check it like ```if (!response.ok) throw new Error('Any error')``` It never throws the error because response.ok is true. However, When I try to request a country that doesn't exist, this api doesn't tell me anything.

Comment: The first fetch request should not be returning a status of 200. When I add the URL in manually, with a country name, it gives me a 404.  https://restcountries.com/v2/name/peeeeee manually returns a 404. But it doesn't in the code.

Comment: If you run this code and view the console in the browser, it returns a status of 200. But if I add it in the browser manually, status is 404.  ```fetch(`https://restcountries.com/v2/name/anycountry`)
    .then(response => {
      //   if (response.status === 404) throw new Error(`Country not found`);
      console.log(response);
      return response.json();
    })```

Comment: I made the mistake of thinking that fetch request would throw a 404 which technically is not a request error. So, In order to test it, I would have to check the response in the next .then block from the previous when I return response.json().

Comment: that's right. an error from the request would be something like a network error (like if the server was down). But even a 404 response is a correct response from the server so is considered 'ok'. It makes sense when you think about it, but it's not completely intuitive.

Comment: Right. The fetch request doesn't generate a 404. So, the promise is fulfilled. Then, in order to check for a response.status, I need to consume the body of that request because the 404 is in the response.json(), Thank you for all of your help.